# Is it possible that cl(A-B) $\subsetneq$ cl(A)-cl(B)

Tags: general-topology

Suppose A,B are two subsets of a Hausdorff space X, is it possible that cl(A-B) $\subsetneq$ cl(A)-cl(B)?

This is a modified exercise from Munkre's topology, the original version doesn't require X to be Hausdorff. Is it possible if X is a general topological space?

Comment: I've edited the question. I am looking for a non-trivial example.

Comment: What about $A=[0,1]$, $B=\{\frac12\}$? In this case, $cl(A-B)=[0,1]$, while $cl(A)-cl(B)=A\setminus B$, so it is certainly true that the first is not a subset of the second...

Comment: Oops! Apologies for misreading the question. Apparently, @5xum read it the same way I did. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completely revised.** Let $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{cl}B$, and let $U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}B$. Let $V$ be any open nbhd of $x$; then $U\cap V$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $B$, and $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so $U\cap V\cap(A\setminus B)\ne\varnothing$. Thus, $V\cap(A\setminus B)\ne\varnothing$, so $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus B)$, and the desired proper inclusion is impossible: $(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{cl}B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I have tried several examples in Hausdorff space, it seems that cl(A)-cl(B) is always included (strictly or not) in cl(A-B). So I posted this question to see if the inverse holds. In the question, the left is a proper subset of the right. So I don't think your examples work.

Comment: @spiritfire: Look again: I gave you examples showing that each side can be properly contained in the other. Thus, in general you can't assume an inclusion in either direction.

Comment: If A=(0,1), B=(1,2), then A-B=A, cl(A-B)=[0,1], cl(A)-cl(B)=[0,1), cl(A)-cl(B)$\subsetneq $ cl(A-B); if A=(1,2),B=(0,1),then cl(A-B)=[1,2], cl(A)-cl(B)=(1,2],  cl(A)-cl(B)$\subsetneq $ cl(A-B). Am I wrong?

Comment: @spiritfire: Sorry, you're right about that. Your original question wasn't clear; I thought that you were asking for an example like my first and added the second as a careless afterthought.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make myself clear. I found that my non-Hausdorff example was wrong and the question is changed to a more general scope.

Comment: @spiritfire: The current version is entirely clear. And assuming that I've not suffered another mental hiccup, I've answered it in the negative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42115/discussion-between-spiritfire-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @spiritfire: Sorry: I went offline just after writing my previous comment and didn’t see the chat request.